# Can't place GraphQL custom type as a Postman variable

Tags: post, graphql, postman, graphql-mutation

Has anyone had luck with placing a GraphQL custom type argument as a Postman or Graphql variable? I'm kinda spinning in circles right now, I hope a fresh pair of eyes could point me in the right direction.
What I'm trying to do is to send a mutation request using Postman. The problem I'm having is that the method I'm calling is taking a custom type as an argument. Placing the content of that variable as GraphQL variable or Postman variable is giving me a headache. I can't embedd pictures yet, so here are the links (they are safe).

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93q4R.png)

This custom type is a JSON-like structure, consisting of two enums and a set of primitive types (strings, ints...). I can screenshot the entire thing but basically that's it: two enums followed by strings, ints...
[Custom type definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0bq5.png)

What I've tried so far:

- Simply hardcoding the request in Postman works but I wish to send multiple requests with varying data
- Placing it in a GraphQL variable results in error message

> {
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Bad request - invalid request body.",
> "locations": []
> }
> ],
> "data": null
> }

- Placing the custom type content as a Postman environment variable works, but I'm getting a syntax error (although the request passes...).
  Request body is below. Hardcoding it and using a Postman variable produces the same request body, apart from the syntax error.

```
query: "mutation {
  createApplication(request: { 
    applicationKind: NEW_ISSUANCE,
    documentKind: REGULAR_PASSPORT,
    personalData: {
        timestamp: null,
        firstname: "NAME",
        lastname: "LASTNAME",
        middlename: "MIDDLENAME",
        dateOfBirth: "2011-09-28",
        citizenshipCountryCode: "USA",
        gender: MALE,
        personalNumber: "3344",
        placeOfBirth: "CHICAGO",
        municipalityOfBirth: "SOUTH",
        countryCodeOfBirth: "USA"},
    addressData:{
        street: "WEST",
        municipality: "EAST",
        place: "CHICAGO",
          country: {
            code: "USA",
            name: null
          },
        entrance: "б",
        flat: "13",
        number: "35"}
}) 
    {
    __typename
    ... on AsyncTaskStatus {
      taskID
      state
      payload {
        ... on ApplicationUpdated {
          applicationID
          applicationNumber
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    ... on Error {
      ...errorData
      __typename
    }
  }
}

fragment errorData on Error {
  __typename
  code
  message
}"
```

[Postman variable with a squiggly line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmuC2.png)

I'm spinning in circles right now. Has anyone had any luck with Postman requests of this kind?
I can post more info, screenshots...just let me know. I'll be watching this topic closely and provide feedback.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: whats the error in postman if you hover over it

Comment: Hi. It's "Syntax error: Expected name, found {"

Comment: could you paste the postman body in the question

Comment: I've updated the question with a request body.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please add a the variable in variable section as :

```
{
"request": {{request}}
}
```

and then refer this in your query as

```
$request
```

Comment: Hi. I tried that. Doint that results in 
   ` "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Bad request - invalid request body.",
            "locations": []
        }
    ],
    "data": null`
Entire request is a variable starting with { and finishing with }

Comment: Try json data raw body type instead then

Comment: I had to change the Content-type in the header to application/graphql and body type to raw and it works! Thanks.
Why won't it resolve the GraphQL variable in the GraphQL body type is beyond me...